# Is it possible to filter children by used className in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have written something like this, but it is not working:

```
var MenuElement = (props) => (
    <div>
        {React.cloneElement(React.Children.toArray(props.children).filter(x => x.className.contains("icon"))[0],
            {
                style: {
                    width: "20px"
                }
            }
        )}
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
    <MenuElement>
        <div className="icon">
            <i className="fab fa-html5">icon</i>
        </div>
        <div className="description">
            <span>description</span>
        </div>
    </MenuElement>, 
    document.getElementById("hiddenMenu")
);
```

I have searched for this problem in Stackoverflow but found nothing.
I have found "classList" property somewhere but it was also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `className` is a prop, so you need to look for the `x.props.className`. To see if a string is a substring of another string you want to use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), and it might be a good idea to guard against elements that don't have a `className` prop at all.

**Example**

```js
var MenuElement = props => {
  const icons = React.Children.toArray(props.children).filter(
    x => x.props.className && x.props.className.includes("icon")
  );

  if (icons.length === 0) {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {React.cloneElement(icons[0], {
        style: {
          width: "20px"
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <MenuElement>
    <div className="icon">
      <i className="fab fa-html5">icon</i>
    </div>
    <div className="description">
      <span>description</span>
    </div>
  </MenuElement>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```